# Excel: find multiple strings in one cell, and list them in another cell, according to strings in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1:
product1, product2, product5, dkwex, otherwords

(without sequence)

Cell B1: product1

Cell B2: product2

How to find out strings in Cell A1 according to cell B1 and B2, and list the results in Cell C1?

Cell C1 should be: product1, product2

Comment: there are more than 200 words to find, so the range of cell B is 1 to 250

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then give a try on below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B1:B10,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:B10,A1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know it works!